# Can i hide post page name in jquery script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can i hide `process.php` page name from this script. I mean can I send data to another page in other secure method so that client can not see the page name, I think it is not that secure for a professional/commercial website.

```
function sess(x) {
     var x;                     
     jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'process.php',
         data: {
                 y: x                       
               },                   
         success: function (html) {
                    $(".msg").html(html).show();
                  }
     });
     setTimeout(function(){$('.msg').hide();}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: It will not show page name by default. If someone do inspect element in the browser and go to network then only he or see able to see that.

Comment: A browser has to know the URL of the PHP script for it to work. Secure data should be sent through POST.

Comment: thats what i am saying.. i know if someone does page inspection then he/ she will see.. but i want to know in big websites how data are sent .. do they use same method ??? @gcampbell

Comment: don't use ajax if you want to protect process.php

Comment: If you are using an Apache server, take a look at URL rewriting : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html , you can change process.php?id=5 to no-page-name-5 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, NO.. there is no way to completely hide the name of the page you are posting to. The browser must know where to POST your data to.

However, just because the user knows of the existence of a specific page, doesn't mean they should be able to exploit it. You can take some measures to protect yourself.

- Don't `echo` or `print` any superfluous information in your `process.php` page.  This includes error messages..!
- Only `echo` the minimum response needed by your Javascript. Sometimes a response may not be needed.  While other times just an `OK` will suffice, other times just a `TRUE` or `FALSE` will work.  Of course sometimes you will need to return data or full objects.
- You could generate a random value and store it in a cookie and include it with every AJAX request.  Then, you can validate on the server side and only output data if that value is valid.

Ideally, you want the user to see absolutely nothing if they navigate to your `process.php` page.

Hope that helps..!

Comment: thanks .. i thought user could axploit my site by seeing .. post page name in jquery post methid script.